# Efficient way to apply multiple filters to pandas DataFrame or Series

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, filter

I have a scenario where a user wants to **apply several filters to a Pandas DataFrame or Series object**.  Essentially, I want to efficiently chain a bunch of filtering (comparison operations) together that are specified at run-time by the user.

- The filters should be **additive** (aka each one applied should narrow results).
- I'm currently using `reindex()` (as below) but this creates a new object each time and copies the underlying data (if I understand the documentation correctly). I want to avoid this unnecessary copying as it will be really inefficient when filtering a big Series or DataFrame.
- I'm thinking that using `apply()`, `map()`, or something similar might be better.  I'm pretty new to Pandas though so still trying to wrap my head around everything.
- Also, I would like to expand this so that **the dictionary passed in can include the columns to operate on** and filter an entire DataFrame based on the input dictionary.  However, I'm assuming whatever works for a Series can be easily expanded to a DataFrame.

### TL;DR

I want to take a dictionary of the following form and apply each operation to a given Series object and return a 'filtered' Series object.

```
relops = {'>=': [1], '<=': [1]}
```

### Long Example

I'll start with an example of what I have currently and just filtering a single Series object.  Below is the function I'm currently using:

```
   def apply_relops(series, relops):
        """
        Pass dictionary of relational operators to perform on given series object
        """
        for op, vals in relops.iteritems():
            op_func = ops[op]
            for val in vals:
                filtered = op_func(series, val)
                series = series.reindex(series[filtered])
        return series
```

The user provides a dictionary with the operations they want to perform:

```
>>> df = pandas.DataFrame({'col1': [0, 1, 2], 'col2': [10, 11, 12]})
>>> print df
>>> print df
   col1  col2
0     0    10
1     1    11
2     2    12

>>> from operator import le, ge
>>> ops ={'>=': ge, '<=': le}
>>> apply_relops(df['col1'], {'>=': [1]})
col1
1       1
2       2
Name: col1
>>> apply_relops(df['col1'], relops = {'>=': [1], '<=': [1]})
col1
1       1
Name: col1
```

Again, the 'problem' with my above approach is that I think there is a lot of possibly unnecessary copying of the data for the in-between steps.

Comment: Also, I'm fully aware that this approach to the problem might be way off.  So maybe rethinking the entire approach would be useful.  I just want to allow users to specify a set of filter operations at runtime and execute them.

Comment: I'm wondering if pandas can do similar things as data.table in R: df[col1<1,,][col2>=1]

Comment: `df.query` and `pd.eval` seem like good fits for your use case. For information on the `pd.eval()` family of functions, their features and use cases, please visit [Dynamic Expression Evaluation in pandas using pd.eval()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53779986/dynamic-expression-evaluation-in-pandas-using-pd-eval).

Answer (score 369, accepted):

Pandas (and numpy) allow for [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), which will be much more efficient:

```
In [11]: df.loc[df['col1'] >= 1, 'col1']
Out[11]: 
1    1
2    2
Name: col1

In [12]: df[df['col1'] >= 1]
Out[12]: 
   col1  col2
1     1    11
2     2    12

In [13]: df[(df['col1'] >= 1) & (df['col1'] <=1 )]
Out[13]: 
   col1  col2
1     1    11
```

If you want to write helper functions for this, consider something along these lines:

```
In [14]: def b(x, col, op, n): 
             return op(x[col],n)

In [15]: def f(x, *b):
             return x[(np.logical_and(*b))]

In [16]: b1 = b(df, 'col1', ge, 1)

In [17]: b2 = b(df, 'col1', le, 1)

In [18]: f(df, b1, b2)
Out[18]: 
   col1  col2
1     1    11
```

Update: [pandas 0.13 has a query method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) for these kind of use cases, assuming column names are valid identifiers the following works (and can be more efficient for large frames as it uses [numexpr](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr) behind the scenes):

```
In [21]: df.query('col1 <= 1 & 1 <= col1')
Out[21]:
   col1  col2
1     1    11
```

Comment: Your right, boolean is more efficient since it doesn't make a copy of the data.  However, my scenario is a bit more tricky than your example.  The input I receive is a dictionary defining what filters to apply.  My example could do something like `df[(ge(df['col1'], 1) & le(df['col1'], 1)]`.  The issue for me really is the dictionary with the filters could contain lots of operators and chaining them together is cumbersome.  Maybe I could add each intermediate boolean array to a big array and then just use `map` to apply the `and` operator to them?

Comment: @durden2.0 I've added an idea for a helper function, which I think is similar to what you are looking for :)

Comment: That looks very close to what I came up with!  Thanks for the example.  Why does `f()` need to take `*b` instead of just `b`? Is this so user of `f()` could still use the optional `out` parameter to `logical_and()`?  This leads to another small side-question.  What is the performance benefit/trade off of passing in array via `out()` vs. using the one returned from `logical_and()`? Thanks again!

Comment: Nevermind, I didn't look close enough.  The `*b` is necessary because you are passing the two arrays `b1` and `b2` and you need to unpack them when calling `logical_and`.  However, the other question still stands.  Is there a performance benefit to passing in an array via `out` parameter to `logical_and()` vs just using its' return value?

Comment: No, sorry I was lazy and didn't try it myself.  I was just curious of any theoretical information behind it.

Comment: this 'helper function' method seems to have greater potential to be used dynamically (e.g. allow for checking whether or not a filter was passed) vs. the query string which is static and hard-coded. However, this answer was originally posted in 2012, so I am wondering if it is still relevant now or if there are easier ways available?

Comment: @user5359531 the string is just a string and so can be created dynamically and passed to the query method. The update (of the query method) is from 2014 and still valid!

Comment: Great answer, which led me to what I needed. Small note - seeing `*b`, I thought maybe I could pass multiple (ie more than 2) functions through, but `np.logical_and` only takes 2 arguments. My quick fix was to change `f` to something like (excuse the terrible comment-formatting): `def f(x, *bs): base = bs[0]; for b in bs[1:]: base = np.logical_and(base, b); return x[(base)]` - now you can pass in an arbitrary number of filters (even just 1 - it won't ever call `np.logical_and` in that case!)

Comment: I don't think columns that are not valid identifiers can be used with the query method: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/6508

Comment: @EmilGotsev ah, yes, it does look like that's no longer supported. You used to be able to have access to all variables iirc.

Comment: hey what about the or filter

Comment: @dwanderson you can pass a list of conditions to  np.logical_and.reduce for multiple conditions. Example: np.logical_and.reduce([df['a']==3, df['b']>10,df['c'].isin(1,3,5)])

Answer (score 64):

Chaining conditions creates long lines, which are discouraged by PEP8.
Using the `.query` method forces to use strings, which is powerful but unpythonic and not very dynamic.

Once each of the filters is in place, one approach could be:

```
import numpy as np
import functools
def conjunction(*conditions):
    return functools.reduce(np.logical_and, conditions)

c_1 = data.col1 == True
c_2 = data.col2 < 64
c_3 = data.col3 != 4

data_filtered = data[conjunction(c_1,c_2,c_3)]
```

`np.logical` operates on and is fast, but does not take more than two arguments, which is handled by `functools.reduce`.

Note that this still has some redundancies:

- Shortcutting does not happen on a global level
- Each of the individual conditions runs on the whole initial data

Still, I expect this to be efficient enough for many applications and it is very readable. You can also make a disjunction (wherein only one of the conditions needs to be true) by using `np.logical_or` instead:

```
import numpy as np
import functools
def disjunction(*conditions):
    return functools.reduce(np.logical_or, conditions)

c_1 = data.col1 == True
c_2 = data.col2 < 64
c_3 = data.col3 != 4

data_filtered = data[disjunction(c_1,c_2,c_3)]
```

Comment: Is there a way to implement this for a variable number of conditions? I have tried appending each `c_1`, `c_2`, `c_3`, ... `c_n` in a list, and then passing `data[conjunction(conditions_list)]` but get an error `ValueError: Item wrong length 5 instead of 37.` Also tried `data[conjunction(*conditions_list)]` but I get a different result than `data[conjunction(c_1, c_2, c_3, ... c_n )]`, not sure what is going on.

Comment: Found a solution to the error elsewhere. `data[conjunction(*conditions_list)]` does work after packing the dataframes into a list, and [unpacking the list in place](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)

Comment: I just left a comment on the above answer with a much sloppier version, and then noticed your answer. Very clean, I like it a lot!

Comment: This is a great answer!

Comment: i'd used: `df[f_2 & f_3 & f_4 & f_5 ]` with `f_2 = df["a"] >= 0`etc. No need for that function... (nice use of higher order function though...)

Comment: not to nitpick but just to confirm - you need `c_1`, `c_2` and `c_3` in your disjunction function above not c1, c2,and c3 ?

Answer (score 47):

**Simplest of All Solutions:**

Use:

```
filtered_df = df[(df['col1'] >= 1) & (df['col1'] <= 5)]
```

**Another Example**, To filter the dataframe for values belonging to Feb-2018, use the below code

```
filtered_df = df[(df['year'] == 2018) & (df['month'] == 2)]
```

Comment: i am using variable instead of constant.  getting error.  df[df[ ]][df[ ]] gives warning message but gives correct answer.

Answer (score 15):

Since [pandas 0.22 update](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#flexible-comparisons), comparison options are available like:

- gt (greater than)
- lt (less than)
- eq (equals to)
- ne (not equals to)
- ge (greater than or equals to)

and many more. These functions return boolean array. Let's see how we can use them:

```
# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [0, 1, 2,3,4,5], 'col2': [10, 11, 12,13,14,15]})

# get values from col1 greater than or equals to 1
df.loc[df['col1'].ge(1),'col1']

1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5

# where co11 values is between 0 and 2
df.loc[df['col1'].between(0,2)]

 col1 col2
0   0   10
1   1   11
2   2   12

# where col1 > 1
df.loc[df['col1'].gt(1)]

 col1 col2
2   2   12
3   3   13
4   4   14
5   5   15
```

Comment: I think this is the cleanest and most efficient option and you can also assign these conditions e. g. `c0 = df.loc[:, "area"].eq("TNG")` and use them for slicing e. g. `df.loc[c0 & c1, ...]`.

Answer (score 5):

Why not do this?

```
def filt_spec(df, col, val, op):
    import operator
    ops = {'eq': operator.eq, 'neq': operator.ne, 'gt': operator.gt, 'ge': operator.ge, 'lt': operator.lt, 'le': operator.le}
    return df[ops[op](df[col], val)]
pandas.DataFrame.filt_spec = filt_spec
```

Demo:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4,5], 'b':[5,4,3,2,1]})
df.filt_spec('a', 2, 'ge')
```

Result:

```
   a  b
 1  2  4
 2  3  3
 3  4  2
 4  5  1
```

You can see that column 'a' has been filtered where a >=2.

This is slightly faster (typing time, not performance) than operator chaining. You could of course put the import at the top of the file.

Answer (score 4):

e can also select rows based on values of a column that are not in a list or any iterable. We will create boolean variable just like before, but now we will negate the boolean variable by placing ~ in the front.

For example

```
list = [1, 0]
df[df.col1.isin(list)]
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to check any/all of multiple columns for a value, you can do:

```
df[(df[['HomeTeam', 'AwayTeam']] == 'Fulham').any(axis=1)]
```