# Selecting with complex criteria from pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

For example I have simple DF:

```
import pandas as pd
from random import randint

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [randint(1, 9) for x in range(10)],
                   'B': [randint(1, 9)*10 for x in range(10)],
                   'C': [randint(1, 9)*100 for x in range(10)]})
```

Can I select values from 'A' for which corresponding values for 'B' will be greater than 50, and for 'C' - not equal to 900, using methods and idioms of Pandas?

Comment: `df.query` and `pd.eval` seem like good fits for this use case. For information on the `pd.eval()` family of functions, their features and use cases, please visit [Dynamic Expression Evaluation in pandas using pd.eval()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53779986/dynamic-expression-evaluation-in-pandas-using-pd-eval).

Comment: Might as well check @Gecko 's answer in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13611065/efficient-way-to-apply-multiple-filters-to-pandas-dataframe-or-series

Answer (score 536, accepted):

Sure!  Setup:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from random import randint
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [randint(1, 9) for x in range(10)],
                   'B': [randint(1, 9)*10 for x in range(10)],
                   'C': [randint(1, 9)*100 for x in range(10)]})
>>> df
   A   B    C
0  9  40  300
1  9  70  700
2  5  70  900
3  8  80  900
4  7  50  200
5  9  30  900
6  2  80  700
7  2  80  400
8  5  80  300
9  7  70  800
```

We can apply column operations and get boolean Series objects:

```
>>> df["B"] > 50
0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
4    False
5    False
6     True
7     True
8     True
9     True
Name: B
>>> (df["B"] > 50) & (df["C"] != 900)
```

or

```
>>> (df["B"] > 50) & ~(df["C"] == 900)
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
5    False
6    False
7    False
8    False
9    False
```

[Update, to switch to new-style `.loc`]:

And then we can use these to index into the object.  For read access, you can chain indices:

```
>>> df["A"][(df["B"] > 50) & (df["C"] != 900)]
2    5
3    8
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

but you can get yourself into trouble because of the difference between a view and a copy doing this for write access.  You can use `.loc` instead:

```
>>> df.loc[(df["B"] > 50) & (df["C"] != 900), "A"]
2    5
3    8
Name: A, dtype: int64
>>> df.loc[(df["B"] > 50) & (df["C"] != 900), "A"].values
array([5, 8], dtype=int64)
>>> df.loc[(df["B"] > 50) & (df["C"] != 900), "A"] *= 1000
>>> df
      A   B    C
0     9  40  300
1     9  70  700
2  5000  70  900
3  8000  80  900
4     7  50  200
5     9  30  900
6     2  80  700
7     2  80  400
8     5  80  300
9     7  70  800
```

Answer (score 84):

Another solution is to use the [query](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) method:

```
import pandas as pd

from random import randint
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [randint(1, 9) for x in xrange(10)],
                   'B': [randint(1, 9) * 10 for x in xrange(10)],
                   'C': [randint(1, 9) * 100 for x in xrange(10)]})
print df

   A   B    C
0  7  20  300
1  7  80  700
2  4  90  100
3  4  30  900
4  7  80  200
5  7  60  800
6  3  80  900
7  9  40  100
8  6  40  100
9  3  10  600

print df.query('B > 50 and C != 900')

   A   B    C
1  7  80  700
2  4  90  100
4  7  80  200
5  7  60  800
```

Now if you want to change the returned values in column A you can save their index:

```
my_query_index = df.query('B > 50 & C != 900').index
```

....and use `.iloc` to change them i.e:

```
df.iloc[my_query_index, 0] = 5000

print df

      A   B    C
0     7  20  300
1  5000  80  700
2  5000  90  100
3     4  30  900
4  5000  80  200
5  5000  60  800
6     3  80  900
7     9  40  100
8     6  40  100
9     3  10  600
```

Answer (score 58):

And remember to use parenthesis!

Keep in mind that `&` operator takes a precedence over operators such as `>` or `<` etc. That is why

```
4 < 5 & 6 > 4
```

evaluates to `False`. Therefore if you're using `pd.loc`, you need to put brackets around your logical statements, otherwise you get an error. That's why do:

```
df.loc[(df['A'] > 10) & (df['B'] < 15)]
```

instead of

```
df.loc[df['A'] > 10 & df['B'] < 15]
```

which would result in

> TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [float64] array with a scalar of type [bool]

Answer (score 8):

You can use pandas it has some built in functions for comparison. So if you want to select values of "A" that are met by the conditions of "B" and "C" (assuming you want back a DataFrame pandas object)

```
df[['A']][df.B.gt(50) & df.C.ne(900)]
```

`df[['A']]` will give you back column A in DataFrame format.

pandas `gt` function will return the positions of column B that are greater than 50 and `ne` will return the positions not equal to 900.

Answer (score 3):

It may be more readable to assign each condition to a variable, especially if there are a lot of them (maybe with descriptive names) and chain them together using bitwise operators such as (`&` or `|`). As a bonus, you don't need to worry about brackets `()` because each condition evaluates independently.

```py
m1 = df['B'] > 50
m2 = df['C'] != 900
m3 = df['C'].pow(2) > 1000
m4 = df['B'].mul(4).between(50, 500)

# filter rows where all of the conditions are True
df[m1 & m2 & m3 & m4]

# filter rows of column A where all of the conditions are True
df.loc[m1 & m2 & m3 & m4, 'A']
```

or put the conditions in a list and reduce it via `bitwise_and` from `numpy` (wrapper for `&`).

```py
conditions = [
    df['B'] > 50,
    df['C'] != 900,
    df['C'].pow(2) > 1000,
    df['B'].mul(4).between(50, 500)
]
# filter rows of A where all of conditions are True
df.loc[np.bitwise_and.reduce(conditions), 'A']
```