# How to create a new dataframe from existing dataframe with certain condition - python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe looks like below.

```
   text      country    language
-----------------------------------
  football     US         Eng
  baseball     JP         Jpn
  swimming     UK         Eng
  running      FR         Fra
  rugby        NZ         Eng
  Hockey       NL         Dut
```

In python, I want to extract rows which contain strings 'ball' and 'ing' in the column 'text' and make a new dataframe with those rows like below.

```
   text      country    language
-----------------------------------
  football     US         Eng
  baseball     JP         Jpn
  swimming     UK         Eng
  running      FR         Fra
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using pandas, you can [slice using multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15315452/selecting-with-complex-criteria-from-pandas-dataframe), just watch out for tricky parenthesis on the syntax.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['foo', 'bar', 'fooing', 'barball'],
                   'B': [1, 2, 3, 4]})

df_slice = df[(df.A.str.contains('ing')) | (df.A.str.contains('ball'))]
```

That should yield

```
df_slice
A        B
fooing   3
barball  4
```

If your goal is to slice in words that *end* in `ing` or `ball`, use `endswith()` instead of `contains()` in the conditions. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks! Can I ask you one more? What if there are multiple conditions (let's say more than two)? Is it possible to do it like condition = [~,~,~,~], df.A.str.contains(condition)?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. `df.A.str.contains()` takes only a `str` as argument, not a condition. You can chain conditions with `&` and `|` and a few parenthesis on the slice, of course. The goal is to create a series with `True` or  `False` elements and feed it to the dataframe, this will create the requested slice.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot!