# set value only according column name in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
    max_speed  shield  new
1   1          2       3
2   4          5       6
```

I got this dataframe, and I want to assign a value according to some column names.
like this df.loc[df['max_speed']==1, df['shield']==2, new] = 10
then I will get the new dataframe:

```
    max_speed  shield  new
 1  1          2       10
 2  4          5       6
```

Anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

you are pretty close.

```
df.loc[(df.max_speed == 1) & (df.shield == 2), "new"] = 10
```

For further reading, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15315452/selecting-with-complex-criteria-from-pandas-dataframe).

Comment: coldspeed, it's 8 after midnight, you never sleep? :)

Comment: Sleep is for the weak

Comment: It works! I got one more question, I can not find the method you provided in the DataFrame.loc document. Hwo do you know this method works?

Answer (score 2):

Alternative with `where` if you want to change the value if doesnt fullfill your conditions:

```
df['new'] = np.where((df['max_speed']==1) & (df['shield']==2) , 10, df['new'])
```