# selecting from a pandas.dataframe based on a column of arrays

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with a column containing arrays (all 1x9 arrays). For all rows in that column, I wish to find the ones where the third element is 1 and pick out the values from another column in the corresponding row. 
For example, I wish to pick out the 'cal_nCa' value （116） where the second element in info_trig is 0

```
    info_trig                        cal_nCa
0   [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]        128   
1   [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]         79  
2   [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]        116   
3   [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]         82
```

I tried something in line of `df["A"][(df["B"] > 50)]`, based on [Selecting with complex criteria from pandas.DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15315452/selecting-with-complex-criteria-from-pandas-dataframe).

When selecting the desired rows:

```
data["info_trig"][:][3]
```

I only succeed selecting a specific row and the third element in that row. But unable to select all the third element in every row. A loop could work but I hope there is a cleaner way out.

Comment: Sorry for the odd formatting, I failed to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

Using `str` to access the column 3rd position value

```
data["info_trig"].str[3]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data.apply(lambda x: x['cal_nCa'] if x['info_trig'][1] == 0 else 0, axis = 1)
```

This will return a Series that only remain value in `cal_nCa` when the second element value in `info_trig` is `0`:

```
0      0
1      0
2    116
3      0
dtype: int64
```

Or you can only select the rows you want by this:

```
data[data.apply(lambda x: True if x['info_trig'][1] == 0 else False, axis = 1)]
```

Hope it will help you.