# Is there a good pythonic way to filter dataframe with multiple conditions?

Tags: python, pandas

Looking for an efficient way to do multi-condition filter (better not iterating through each row).

Original Data:

```
fruit      price  qty   comment
apple       1.5   10    In Stock
apple       0.7   20    In Stock
pear        3.0   5     In Stock
pear        2.0   5     In Stock 
pear        1.2   30    Out Stock
```

Filer logic:

```
if fruit = 'apple'  keep price = 1.5
if fruit = 'Pear'   keep qty = 5
```

expected output:

```
fruit      price  qty   comment
apple       1.5   10    In Stock
pear        3.0   5     In Stock
pear        2.0   5     In Stock
```

Comment: So `df[((df["fruit"]=="apple")&(df["price"]==1.5))|((df["fruit"]=="pear")&(df["qty"]==5))]`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting with complex criteria from pandas.DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15315452/selecting-with-complex-criteria-from-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create boolean masks with `&` and then need '|' for both mask merging.

```
m1 = ((df['fruit']=='apple') & (df['price']==1.5))
m2 = ((df['fruit']=='pear') & (df['qty']==5))
df.loc[m1 | m2]
```

Output:

```
   fruit    price   qty comment
0   apple   1.5 10  In Stock
2   pear    3.0 5   In Stock
3   pear    2.0 5   In Stock
```