# Pandas - select rows based on values within a list of columns

Tags: python, pandas

Related: [Selecting with complex criteria from pandas.DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15315452/selecting-with-complex-criteria-from-pandas-dataframe)

I have some DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['apple1', 'apple2', 'apple3', 'apple4', 'orange1', 'orange2', 'orange3', 'orange4'], 
                   'A': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0, 0], 
                  'B': [0.10, -0.15, 0.25, -0.55, 0.50, -0.51, 0.70, 0], 
                  'C': [0, 0, 0.25, -0.55, 0.50, -0.51, 0.70, 0.90],
                  'D': [0.10, -0.15, 0.25, 0, 0.50, -0.51, 0.70, 0.90]})
df
name    A   B   C   D
0   apple1  0   0.10    0.00    0.10
1   apple2  0   -0.15   0.00    -0.15
2   apple3  0   0.25    0.25    0.25
3   apple4  0   -0.55   -0.55   0.00
4   orange1 0   0.50    0.50    0.50
5   orange2 0   -0.51   -0.51   -0.51
6   orange3 0   0.70    0.70    0.70
7   orange4 0   0.00    0.90    0.90
```

Now let's say I want to select all the rows with values less than 0.25 in `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D`:

```
df[(df['A'] < 0.25) & 
  (df['B'] < 0.25) &
  (df['C'] < 0.25) &
  (df['D'] < 0.25)]
    name    A   B   C   D
0   apple1  0   0.10    0.00    0.10
1   apple2  0   -0.15   0.00    -0.15
3   apple4  0   -0.55   -0.55   0.00
5   orange2 0   -0.51   -0.51   -0.51
```

Great, but **can I achieve the same thing using a list of columns as input?**

Imagine that I wanted to filter on 100 columns instead of 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, because you have the same condition over multiple columns, you can use [`.all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) over `axis=1` to check if the condition is `True` for *all* the selected columns:

```
df[df.loc[:, 'A':].lt(0.25).all(axis=1)]

      name  A     B     C     D
0   apple1  0  0.10  0.00  0.10
1   apple2  0 -0.15  0.00 -0.15
3   apple4  0 -0.55 -0.55  0.00
5  orange2  0 -0.51 -0.51 -0.51
```

---

If your columns arn't so well ordered, use double brackets for selection of your data:

```
df[df[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']].lt(0.25).all(axis=1)]
```

**Note:** [`.lt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lt.html) is same as `<` and stands for *"**l**ess **t**han"*

---

**In case** you have lot of columns with a single letter, which would be too much to select manually, we can use `DataFrame.filter` with `regex`:

```
df[df.filter(regex='[A-Z]').lt(0.25).all(axis=1)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) with `axis=1` to performance a [`boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).

```
df[(df[['A','B','C','D']]<0.25).all(axis=1)]
```

**Output**

```
      name  A     B     C     D
0   apple1  0  0.10  0.00  0.10
1   apple2  0 -0.15  0.00 -0.15
3   apple4  0 -0.55 -0.55  0.00
5  orange2  0 -0.51 -0.51 -0.51
```

**Another approach: [`pd.Index.difference`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html)**

```
df[df[df.columns.difference(['name'])].lt(0.25).all(axis=1)]
```

Comment: nice, i'd add in `filter` to show how he can filter columns by regex (since he possible has 100+) or `iloc` or `.loc` to integer or name slice columns