# Applying an IF condition in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using the 2 optional codes to create a new column in my df and include the values wanted as well:

Option 1

```
cov19.loc[cov19['cases'] <= 10, 'estrats'] = 'Very Low' 
cov19.loc[cov19['cases'] > 10 and <= 50, 'estrats'] = 'Low' 
cov19.loc[cov19['cases'] > 50 and <= 100, 'estrats'] = 'Medium' 
cov19.loc[cov19['cases'] > 100 and <= 1000, 'estrats'] = 'High' 
cov19.loc[cov19['cases'] > 1000, 'estrats'] = 'Very High'
```

Error returned 1:

```
cov19.loc[cov19['set_of_numbers'] > 10 and <= 50, 'estrats'] = 'Low'
                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Optional code 2

```
cov19.loc[cov19['cases'] <= 10, 'estrats'] = 'Very Low' 
cov19.loc[cov19['cases'] > 10 and cov19['cases'] <= 50, 'estrats'] = 'Low' 
cov19.loc[cov19['cases'] > 50 and cov19['cases'] <= 100, 'estrats'] = 'Medium' 
cov19.loc[cov19['cases'] > 100 and cov19['cases']<= 1000, 'estrats'] = 'High' 
cov19.loc[cov19['cases'] > 1000, 'estrats'] = 'Very High'
```

Error returned 2

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15315452/selecting-with-complex-criteria-from-pandas-dataframe replace and with '&'

Comment: Use `np.where`. Its faster and intuitive.

Comment: I've got his message after use the '&' sign to join: TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [float64] array with a scalar of type [bool]

Answer (score 2):

This is what you would want:

```
cov19.loc[(cov19['cases'] > 10) & (cov19['cases'] <= 50), 'estrats'] = 'Low'
```

`&` here does element-wise AND operation and you wrap the operands to it using parentheses.

Also, a bit more clarification about `&` vs `and` :

*`and` is boolean operation where `&` is bitwise. So, when you want to compute the AND operation between individual components of the objects, use `&`*

Comment: Thanks @ParthaMandal, this is what I was looking for. Thanks also for your explanation!