# Syntax error on column name (Last Name) when using Python Script in Power BI

Tags: python, pandas, powerbi

I have been going in circles with this question.  I am writing a simple Python script in Power BI.  I am trying to load a Dataframe and change a particular person's Department in a column based on a conditional column, i.e. if they have a Yes, then the department will change for them for the data.  I could really use some feedback as to how I could change the syntax and if my code is correct.  Specifically, I am getting a syntax error on the name of the Last Name column.  This is what I have:

```
import pandas as pd

final = pd.DataFrame(dataset.loc[:,'Department','Last Name','Employee Promotion'])

for i in pd.final:
    if i in pd.final.loc['Last Name'] = "Carter" and in pd.final.loc['Employee Promotion'] = True:
        new_department = "Admin"
        pd.final(dataset.loc[:,'Department') = new_department
        pass
    ifelse i in pd.final.loc['Last Name'] = "Litwack" and in pd.final.loc['Employee Promotion'] = True: 
        new_department1 = "OAAS"
        pd.final(dataset.loc['Department') = new_department1
    else pd.final.loc['Department']
```

Comment: Hello Paul, welcome to stackoverflow, please read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hello Paul, for future reference, you can use triple backticks to format a block of code, instead of adding single backticks around each individual line.

Answer (score 0):

First off, definitely go through some Python tutorials on Python syntax and `if` statements. Once you've done that, read some of the [Pandas tutorials](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/tutorials.html) as well. Those will get you far.

There are several problems in the lines below. First, there is no `ifelse` statement in Python -- I think you meant `elif`. Second, `=` is the assignment operator. For equality, you need to use `==`. Also, instead of `for i in pd.final:`, I think you meant `for i in final`. Your dataframe is `final`, not `pd.final`.

```
    ifelse i in pd.final.loc['Last Name'] = "Litwack" and in pd.final.loc['Employee Promotion'] = True: 
        new_department1 = "OAAS"
        pd.final(dataset.loc['Department') = new_department1
    else pd.final.loc['Department']
```

---

That should help you resolve syntax errors, but there is a better way to do what you are trying to accomplish. Part of the beauty of Pandas is that it allows for vectorized operations, meaning we don't need to use `for` loops. Below is how one might set a value only for rows that match a condition.

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> df = pd.DataFrame(
        [
            ["ABC", "Carter", True],
            ["ABC", "Carter", False],
            ["ABC", "Litwack", False],
            ["ABC", "Litwack", True],
            ["ABC", "Doe", False],
            ["ABC", "Doe", True]
        ],
        columns = ["Department", "Last Name", "Employee Promotion"])

>>> df
  Department Last Name  Employee Promotion
0        ABC    Carter                True
1        ABC    Carter               False
2        ABC   Litwack               False
3        ABC   Litwack                True
4        ABC       Doe               False
5        ABC       Doe                True
```

You can filter based on a set of criteria using boolean indexing, as in the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/15315507/5666087.

```
>>> mask = (df.loc[:, "Last Name"] == "Carter") & (df.loc[:, "Employee Promotion"])
>>> print(mask)
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
dtype: bool
```

`mask` above is boolean array, where each value indicates whether that row meets our criteria. We can then select the rows that meet our criteria and a column to get values, and we overwrite those values with `=`.

```
df.loc[mask, "Department"] = "Admin"
```