# How to fetch rows with multiple coulmns using python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have below csv file. And i am reading this csv file using pandas dataframe.

**Input:**

[image]

> Now i am trying to fetch if 2 columns **city != null and state != null and
> country == null** then it will return those  row only.

**Output**

[image]

**Code**

```
def fieldValidation(df):
    try:
        nan_rows = df[df['city'].notnull(), df['state'].notnull(), df['country'].isnull()]
        print(nan_rows)
    except Exception as error:
        print(error)
```

Can anyone tell me where i am doing wrong or how can i achive this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selecting with complex criteria from pandas.DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15315452/selecting-with-complex-criteria-from-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `&` for bitwise `AND` instead `,` for filtering by multiple conditions:

```
df1 = df[df['city'].notnull() & df['state'].notnull() & df['country'].isnull()]
```