# How to change pandas column values based on condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have pandas dataframe like

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
a = np.arange(0,8,1)
b = np.arange(10,18,1)
c = np.ones(8)
d = np.column_stack((a,b,c))
e = pd.dataframe(d)
e.loc[(e.iloc[:,-1]<1.01) & (e.iloc[:,-1]>0.99)]=4.0
```

I want to change last column of `e` to `4.0` wherever values are `<1.01 & >0.99`. However, the last line changes all values to `4.0`.  I tried to follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/15315507 above, but looks like not working. Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

In last column selected by columns name with indexing with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), there are all values `4` because in input data are `1` - `c = np.ones(8)`:

```
#working well for unique columns names
e.loc[(e.iloc[:,-1]<1.01) & (e.iloc[:,-1]>0.99), e.columns[-1]]=4.0
```

Or by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) with convert mask to boolean array:

```
#working well for any columns names
e.iloc[((e.iloc[:,-1]<1.01) & (e.iloc[:,-1]>0.99)).to_numpy(), -1]=4.0
```

---

```
print (e)
     0     1    2
0  0.0  10.0  4.0
1  1.0  11.0  4.0
2  2.0  12.0  4.0
3  3.0  13.0  4.0
4  4.0  14.0  4.0
5  5.0  15.0  4.0
6  6.0  16.0  4.0
7  7.0  17.0  4.0
```

Changed data sample:

```
np.random.seed(2022)

a = np.arange(0,8,1)
b = np.arange(10,18,1)
c = np.random.random(8) + 0.5
d = np.column_stack((a,b,c))
e = pd.DataFrame(d)
print (e)
     0     1         2
0  0.0  10.0  0.509359
1  1.0  11.0  0.999058
2  2.0  12.0  0.613384
3  3.0  13.0  0.549974
4  4.0  14.0  1.185408
5  5.0  15.0  0.986988
6  6.0  16.0  1.397657
7  7.0  17.0  1.147452

e.iloc[((e.iloc[:,-1]<1.01) & (e.iloc[:,-1]>0.99)).to_numpy(), -1]=4.0
print (e)
     0     1         2
0  0.0  10.0  0.509359
1  1.0  11.0  4.000000
2  2.0  12.0  0.613384
3  3.0  13.0  0.549974
4  4.0  14.0  1.185408
5  5.0  15.0  0.986988
6  6.0  16.0  1.397657
7  7.0  17.0  1.147452
```

Comment: what does `e.columns[-1]` do in the first code line?  I tried to follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/15315507 but don't see `e.columns[-1]` there.

Comment: @ewr3243 - it is trick for get last column name

Comment: @ewr3243 - print (e.columns) - all colums names, `e.columns[-1]` last columns name