# What is the correct way to use df.query() with multiple conditions?

Tags: pandas, filtering, conditional-operator

Based on the pandas documentation for `query`, I do not understand whether it is correct to use `and`/`or` or `&`/`|` in a query statement with multiple conditions.

**Is there a situation when using both bitwise and boolean operators might be necessary? Is there a best practice for when to use which?**

The documentation [states](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

*For example, the `&` and `|` (bitwise) operators have the precedence of their boolean cousins, `and` and `or`*, but the practical implications are not clear to me.

I have found accepted answers where users use either bitwise or boolean operators, in this case the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15315452/selecting-with-complex-criteria-from-pandas-dataframe) using `query` contains `and` in first case and `&` in second, getting the same results.

Here is an example where the choice of operator does not change the result:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randn(5,2), columns=['A','B'])
df['names'] = list('ABCDE')

query1 = df.query("A > -1 and B < 1 or 'B' in names")

query2 = df.query("A > -1 & B < 1 | 'B' in names")

query1.equals(query2)
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All operations return a boolean (true/false) mask, so it doesn't matter whether you use a bitwise or logical operator. However the result is not the same if your numbers are not 0/1 (True/False):

```
>>> 0 & 1  # same as False & True
0  # False

>>> 0 and 1  # same as False and True
0  # False

>>> 2 & 3
2

>>> 2 and 3
3
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, if you could please expand on 2 points: Can you think of a situation in `query`, where the results would differ? What would you consider better practice for using within query, bitwise or boolean?

Comment: The same code can't work outside of `query` (See the [notes](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html)) because at the end, the query is executed row by row so it doesn't matter. I use bitwise operator everytime when I use Pandas to avoid `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Comment: `'B' in names` proves the code is executed for each row. The vectorized method is to use `B.isin(names)`. Is it clear?