# Filter multiple dataframes and create a new one from the results

Tags: pandas, dataframe, filter

I'm a researcher and I would like to filter 2 dataframes and create a new dataframe where it shares common filtered results of the two. I have used a for-loop for the filter criteria for reference but cannot figure out how to output a new dataframe afterward.

```
    SampleCount = 0
for x in df.index:
    if df.loc[x, "snapshotMp60sHighTicks"] < 0.25 and df.loc[x, "snapshotMp60sLowTicks"] < -1.0:
        SampleCount = SampleCount + 1

dfsorted = df.loc[(df['snapshotMp60sHighTicks'] < 0.25) and (df['snapshotMp60sLowTicks'] < -1.0)]
```

Comment: Pls post a sample of your data and expected output

Comment: hi gtomer- basically i have about 40k data points and as you can see above, i am trying to filter for rows that contain both conditions. What i'd want to do is after the filter has been applied, return a new dataframe with just those results.

Comment: @Borla312 read notice : [mre]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selecting with complex criteria from pandas.DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15315452/selecting-with-complex-criteria-from-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 1):

***You can use query method***

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "col1":[12,15,25,35],
    "col2":[45,55,44,54]
})

df.query('col1 > 25 and col2 < 50')
```