# Drop pandas dataframe row based on max value of a column

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe like so:

```
      p_rel      y_BET  sq_resid
1  0.069370  41.184996  0.292942
2  0.116405  43.101090  0.010953
3  0.173409  44.727748  0.036832
4  0.225629  46.681293  0.540616
5  0.250682  46.980616  0.128191
6  0.294650  47.446113  0.132367
7  0.322530  48.078038  0.235047
```

How do I get rid of the fourth row because it has the max value of sq_resid? note: the max will change from dataset to dataset so just removing the 4th row isn't enough.

I have tried several things such as I can remove the max value which leaves the dataframe like below but haven't been able to remove the whole row.

```
  p_rel      y_BET  sq_resid
1  0.069370  41.184996  0.292942
2  0.116405  43.101090  0.010953
3  0.173409  44.727748  0.036832
4  0.225629  46.681293  Nan
5  0.250682  46.980616  0.128191
6  0.294650  47.446113  0.132367
7  0.322530  48.078038  0.235047
```

Answer (score 30):

You could just filter the df like so:

```
In [255]:
df.loc[df['sq_resid']!=df['sq_resid'].max()]

Out[255]:
      p_rel      y_BET  sq_resid
1  0.069370  41.184996  0.292942
2  0.116405  43.101090  0.010953
3  0.173409  44.727748  0.036832
5  0.250682  46.980616  0.128191
6  0.294650  47.446113  0.132367
```

or [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html#pandas.DataFrame.drop) using [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) which will return the label row of the max value:

```
In [257]:
df.drop(df['sq_resid'].idxmax())

Out[257]:
      p_rel      y_BET  sq_resid
1  0.069370  41.184996  0.292942
2  0.116405  43.101090  0.010953
3  0.173409  44.727748  0.036832
5  0.250682  46.980616  0.128191
6  0.294650  47.446113  0.132367
7  0.322530  48.078038  0.235047
```

Comment: What  if I want to use multiple criteria to drop rows based on several conditions?

Comment: @bibscy see related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13611065/efficient-way-to-apply-multiple-filters-to-pandas-dataframe-or-series