# Split string into conditional statements

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I haven't been able to find an answer to this anywhere, so here it goes:
I have a pandas dataframe df like this:

```
   X  Y name
0  3  1  foo
1  5  2   fa
2  1  3  hoo
3  2  4   ha
```

I can easily find information in df by making conditions (for example df['X' >=3]), which is great. However, I want to make a more generic solution, where I can create a long condition in string form (e.g. '(X >= 3) & (name == foo)'), which could be split into an actual condition, that can be used in a pandas dataframe.
Can anyone suggest a smart solution (if something like this is possible) or redirect me to a similar discussion on the discussion board, where this topic has been debated?

Comment: The [query syntax](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#the-query-method-experimental) sounds like what you're interested in.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficient way to apply multiple filters to pandas DataFrame or Series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13611065/efficient-way-to-apply-multiple-filters-to-pandas-dataframe-or-series)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) for filtering:

```
df = df.query("X >= 3 & name == 'foo'")
```

Comment: Simple and elegant. Thanks for guiding me in the right direction. :)