# How to replace all values in a dataframe based on two conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I'd like to replace all values in a df that are between -0.5 and 0.5 with NaNs.

For just the latter condition this solution works nicely:

```
df[df < 0.5] = np.nan
```

I can't, however, figure out how to add a second condition like:

```
df[-0.5 < df < 0.5] = np.nan
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried: `df[(df < 0.5) & (df > -0.5)]`?

Comment: That works perfectly. Thanks @pault

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficient way to apply multiple filters to pandas DataFrame or Series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13611065/efficient-way-to-apply-multiple-filters-to-pandas-dataframe-or-series)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is to index based on two conditions, `df < 0.5` and `df > -0.5`, such as this:

```
df[(df < 0.5) & (df > -0.5)] = np.nan
```

for instance:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# Example df
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'data1':2*np.random.randn(100),
                    'data2':2*np.random.randn(100)})

# Show example with all values as original
>>> df.head(10)
      data1     data2
0 -0.113909  3.625936
1 -2.795349 -1.362933
2 -3.750103  2.686047
3  3.286711 -2.937002
4 -0.279161 -2.255135
5 -0.394181  3.937575
6 -1.166115  0.776880
7 -2.750386  0.681216
8  1.375598 -1.070675
9 -0.871180 -0.122937


df[(df < 0.5) & (df > -0.5)] = np.nan

# Show df with NaN when between -0.5 and 0.5
>>> df.head(10)
      data1     data2
0       NaN  3.625936
1 -2.795349 -1.362933
2 -3.750103  2.686047
3  3.286711 -2.937002
4       NaN -2.255135
5       NaN  3.937575
6 -1.166115  0.776880
7 -2.750386  0.681216
8  1.375598 -1.070675
9 -0.871180       NaN
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help! If it solves your problem, feel free to [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/how-does-accept-rate-work/65088#65088)!