# python assign variables from values in a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, variables, filter

I have a csv file I'm importing as a list

```
[["df['EPS Rating']>=97"],
 ["df['RS Rating']>=97"],
 ["df['Ind Group RS']<=9"],
 ["df['SMR Rating']<=2"],
 ["df['AD Rating']<=9"],
 ["df['Comp Rating']>=85"],
 ["df['Current Price']>=15"]]
```

I would like to assign each of these to variables c1 to c7 like this

```
c1 = df['EPS Rating']>=97
c2 = df['RS Rating']>=97
c3 = df['Ind Group RS']<=9
c4 = df['SMR Rating']<=2
c5 = df['AD Rating']<=9
c6 = df['Comp Rating']>=85
c7 = df['Current Price']>=15
```

This is so I can use this excellent solution I found by Gecko [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13611065/efficient-way-to-apply-multiple-filters-to-pandas-dataframe-or-series) also shown below. While this solution is great for readability in my case it ends up being huge as I have more than 30 of these filters and many with more than 20 conditions. How can I assign strings in a list to variables?

something like this maybe?

```
For i to end_of_list:
    c[i] = [i].value
```

I hope that explains what I'm trying to do. I'm new to python so I'm still a bit lost. I'm not attached to this idea so if anyone has a better solution I'd love to know it. Thanks

Geckos Original Solution:

```
import numpy as np
import functools
def conjunction(*conditions):
    return functools.reduce(np.logical_and, conditions)

c_1 = data.col1 == True
c_2 = data.col2 < 64
c_3 = data.col3 != 4

data_filtered = data[conjunction(c1,c2,c3)]
```

Comment: why you need to store into the variables?

Comment: so that they can be used with the original solution by Gecko

Comment: The problem I'm seeing here is that in your situation, you're importing a list of dataframe expressions as strings, and in the solution you posted, the `conjuction` function is being applied to the *evaluation* of those expressions. In your situation, how is the actual DataFrame object computed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
strings = [["df['EPS Rating']>=97"],
 ["df['RS Rating']>=97"],
 ["df['Ind Group RS']<=9"],
 ["df['SMR Rating']<=2"],
 ["df['AD Rating']<=9"],
 ["df['Comp Rating']>=85"],
 ["df['Current Price']>=15"]]

filters = []
for i in strings:
    filters.append(eval(i[0]))

data_filtered = df[conjunction(*filters)]
```

You can pass that `conjunction` function a list as long as you unpack it *in place*, as done here.

**Note:** this assumes you have the actual DataFrame object `df` initialized somewhere in your code prior to running.

---

Edit: FWIW, this solution would do exactly what you asked for, creating dynamically assigned variables that hold the evaluation of the expression in the string:

```
for i in range(len(g)):
    x = 'c_{}'.format(i)
    exec('{} = {}'.format(x,g[i][0].strip("\"")))
```

but instantiating variables this way (with no explicit assignment statement) is generally terrible practice (see [link](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html) for further information).

Comment: This first solution is exactly what I didn't even know I was looking for. It works great. Also thanks for including the second and the link to why that is not a good idea. You're help is greatly appricated.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can just hold each item in a dictionary.

```
filter_dict = {}
counter = 1
for item in your_list:
    for i in item:
        filter_dict[f'C{counter}'] = i 
        counter += 1

print(filter_dict)

{'C1': "df['EPS Rating']>=97",
 'C2': "df['RS Rating']>=97",
 'C3': "df['Ind Group RS']<=9",
 'C4': "df['SMR Rating']<=2",
 'C5': "df['AD Rating']<=9",
 'C6': "df['Comp Rating']>=85",
 'C7': "df['Current Price']>=15"}
```

---

this gives you a string version of your object, you'll have to use `eval` to use it in your function.

```
import numpy as np
import functools

def conjunction(*conditions):
    return functools.reduce(np.logical_and, conditions)



df[conjunction([eval(x) for x in filter_dict.values()])
```

Note, the `eval` will cause an error if the object doesn't exist in your dataframe.

Comment: While I wasn't able to get this to work it actually gave me an idea to fix something else I'm working on, so thank you.