# How do you use loc in pandas with more than one condition?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, pandas-loc

I'm looking at [this example](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) from the documentation:

```
df.loc[lambda df: df['shield']==8]
```

How do I extend this with an **OR** condition? I'm trying to do this but it doesn't work:

```
df.loc[lambda df: df['shield']==8 or df['max_speed'] ==1]
```

Also, as a side note, what is the point of the lambda function in this case since:

```
 df.loc[df['shield']==8]
```

works just fine.

Comment: Definitely don't use functions to index for this, they are quite pointless here. Also you should be chaining the conditions with [bitwise operators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators). Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13611065/efficient-way-to-apply-multiple-filters-to-pandas-dataframe-or-series) for more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because working with arrays, here Series is necessary use `butwise OR` by `|` and because priority of operators is necessary add parentheses:

```
df.loc[lambda df: (df['shield']==8) | (df['max_speed'] ==1)]
```

Comment: Thanks. Also, I've never used bitwise operators before. Is it a quirk when working with pandas? Why didn't it just an "or" and "and"?

Comment: @Noobcoder - Exactly you are right, it is like `or` for arrays is `|`, `&` for `AND` and `~` for NOT. This operarors also working in numpy (and pandas too, because pandas built on numpy).