# Extract data from data frame based on two criteria

Tags: python, dataframe

Given the following example.

```py
d = {'col1': [1, 2, 3], 'col2': [6, 7]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df
   col1  col2
0     1     6
1     2     7

newdf[df['col1' ==2]

newdf

   col1  col2
0     2     7
```

Works just fine for single col

but

```py
newdf[df['col1' ==2 & 'col2' == 7]
```

I win error prize.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Efficient way to apply multiple filters to pandas DataFrame or Series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13611065/efficient-way-to-apply-multiple-filters-to-pandas-dataframe-or-series)

Comment: Specifically, see the third example in the accepted answer in the linked question.

Answer (score 0):

- None of the following are correct

  - `newdf[df['col1' ==2]`
  - `newdf[df['col1' ==2 & 'col2' == 7]`
  - `newdf[df['col1' == 2 && 'col2' == 7]`
- Parenthesis must be around each condition
- [Pandas: Boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

```py
import pandas as pd

d = {'col1': [1, 2, 3, 2], 'col2': [6, 7, 8, 9]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

   col1  col2
0     1     6
1     2     7
2     3     8
3     2     9

# specify multiple conditions
newdf = df[(df.col1 == 2) & (df.col2 == 7)]
print(newdf)

   col1  col2
1     2     7
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your statement.
The logical `and` operator in python is

```
and
```

Your statement should be

```
>>> newdf[df[('col1' == 2) & ('col2' == 7)]
```

Thanks @Trenton for the remark.

Comment: This is incorrect. `&&` causes `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. `&&` is not a valid operator in python.