# Dynamically filtering a Pandas DataFrame based on user input

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, optimization, plotly-dash

I would appreciate suggestions for a more computationally efficient way to dynamically filter a Pandas DataFrame.

The size of the DataFrame, `len(df.index)`, is around 680,000.

This code from the callback function of a Plotly Dash dashboard is triggered when points on a scatter graph are selected. These points are passed to `points` as a list of dictionaries containing various properties with keys `'A'` to `'C'`. This allows the user to select a subset of the data in the `pandas.DataFrame` instance `df` for cross-filtering analysis.

```
rows_boolean = pandas.Series([False] * len(df.index))

for point in points:    
    current_condition = ((df['A'] == point['a']) & (df['B'] == point['b']) 
        & (df['C'] >= point['c']) & (df['C'] < point['d']))
    rows_boolean = rows_boolean | current_condition                      

filtered = df.loc[rows_boolean, list_of_column_names]
```

The body of this for loop is very slow as it is iterating over the whole data frame, it is manageable to run it once but not inside a loop.

Note that these filters are not additive, as in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13611065/efficient-way-to-apply-multiple-filters-to-pandas-dataframe-or-series); each successive iteration of the for loop *increases*, rather than decreases, the size of `filtered` (as `|` rather than `&` operator is used).

Note also that I am aware of the existence of the method `df['C'].between(point['c'], point['d'])` as an alternative to the last two comparison operators, however, I only want this comparison to be inclusive at the lower end.

**Solutions I have considered**

Searching the *many* frustratingly similar posts on SO reveals a few ideas which get some of  the way:

- Using `pandas.DataFrame.query()` will require building a (potentially very large) query string as follows:

```
query = ' | '.join([f'((A == {point["a"]}) & (B == {point["b"]}) 
    & (C >= {point["c"]}) & (C < {point["d"]}))' for point in points])                

filtered = df.query(query)
```

My main concern here is that I don’t know how efficient the `query` method becomes when the query passed has several dozen (or even several hundred) conditions strung together. This solution also currently does not allow the selection of columns using `list_of_column_names`.

- Another possible solution could come from implementing something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30778300/14067525).

To reiterate, speed is key here, so I'm not just after something that works, but something that works a darn sight faster than my boolean implementation above:

> There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it. (PEP 20)

Comment: sounds like the bottleneck is your `for` loop, not accessing the rows. Have you done any profiling?

Comment: As @JTanner has kindly clarified in the edit, the speed issue here is the code within the `for` loop. No, I haven't done any profiling - I'm very much a code optimisation novice!

Comment: Could you post a code example that runs and yield performance characteristics similar to your real world case?