# Is there a function in pandas (python) for filtering data on two conditions?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

[image]

I have an excel file that looks like somewhat like the above matrix.

There are two three columns, namely: ID, Object and AE.

I want to create a new column first to copy just the first two letters of **Object** column (e.g., V2, V3 etc.) and put those in a new column named **Object1**.

Secondly, I want to see if for any value of V2 in the newly created column **Object1**, the value of **AE**. If so, I want to get such records. An example matrix is given below:

[image]

Comment: I think you can just do `new_df = df[df['Object'].str.startswith('V2')]`. Or if you only want the ones with 'Yes' in the `AE` column you could use `new_df = df[df['Object'].str.startswith('V2') & (df['AE']=='Yes')]`.

Comment: Anything like [Efficient way to apply multiple filters to pandas DataFrame or Series](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13611065/3890632)?

Comment: @MatthiasFripp. your code can't work because it matches V20, V21, V30, ...

Comment: @Corralien, the question seems to say they want to match on the first two characters of the `Object` column, which mine does. If that's wrong, the poster should clarify the question. It's also unclear what condition they want tested in the `AE` column (if any), and whether they really want an `Object1` column or just want to use that for testing (it's not in the example output).

Comment: @MatthiasFripp, actual the situation that I had, had Object values up to V15 only, that way the code worked perfectly fine for me. Thank you very much.

Thank you all as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Your question should be clearer. Is this code below gives you the result you want?

```
df.loc[(df['Object'].str.extract('^(V\d+)').isin(['V2', 'V3']).any(axis=1))
       & (df['AE'] == 'Yes')]
```