# is there a way to combine these python dataframe modifications into one line

Tags: python, dataframe

I am just a beginner so I apologize for this remedial question. I am wanting to drop some observations from a dataframe.

Is there a way to combine these two lines in to one in python?

```
NHL_Team_R_Stats=NHL_Team_R_Stats[NHL_Team_R_Stats.competition_name != '2011 NHL Regular Season']
NHL_Team_R_Stats=NHL_Team_R_Stats[NHL_Team_R_Stats.competition_name != '2012 NHL Regular Season']
```

I tried

```
NHL_Team_R_Stats=NHL_Team_R_Stats[NHL_Team_R_Stats.competition_name != ('2011 NHL Regular Season','2012 NHL Regular Season')]
```

but it wouldn't work.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: try `not in ('2010 NHL Regular Season','2011 NHL Regular Season')`.

Comment: this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13611065/efficient-way-to-apply-multiple-filters-to-pandas-dataframe-or-series

Comment: @deadshop: it worked when i used & but the line gets pretty long

Answer (score 1):

```
NHL_Team_R_Stats=NHL_Team_R_Stats[(NHL_Team_R_Stats.competition_name != '2010 NHL Regular Season') & (NHL_Team_R_Stats.competition_name != '2011 NHL Regular Season')]
```

the above worked

Answer (score 1):

Using the keyword "isin" and the negation "~" should do the job.

```
# the values you want to filter out
val = ["2011 NHL Regular Season", "2012 NHL Regular Season"]

# ~ returns the inverse of the mask
NHL_Team_R_Stats=NHL_Team_R_Stats.loc[~NHL_Team_R_Stats.competition_name.isin(val)]
```

Comment: Thanks! I did get it working but I learned something new from your response. Appreciated!